# Content is not allowed in prolog - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Yesterday I move to windows 11 and Installed Flutter. It was working fine I also run the default app successfully. But when I run one of my ongoing project it show error like these.

```
[Fatal Error] firebase-annotations-16.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] firebase-annotations-16.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] firebase-annotations-16.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] firebase-annotations-16.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] firebase-annotations-16.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] firebase-annotations-16.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] firebase-annotations-16.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
 .....
```

And also some error like =>

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :firebase_auth > com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.5
      > Could not resolve androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0.
         > Could not parse module metadata https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/browser/browser/1.4.0/browser-1.4.0.module
            > Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
      > Could not resolve androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0.
         > Could not parse module metadata 


..............
```

I try many solutions like

1. Deleting the build and .idea file.
2. Invalidate caches.
3. Moving google() to the top of the repositories.
4. I also create a new project and transfer all file to that project but it did not work.

And many more but none of them work. Please help me.
[image: Starting with these error]
[image: Then these error]
[image: flutter doctor]

Answer (score 0):

Add these plugins

```
  cloud_firestore_web: ^2.6.15
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.15
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I switched to windows 10 and that solve my problem.